# Can I link to a specific file from the account sidebar?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I have the following code in local.xml, but when it is rendered on the frontend, Magento treats it as a directory/path and adds a trailing forward slash to it.  Is there any way I can avoide this?

```
<customer_account>
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-"               template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
            <name>free_returns_label</name>
            <path>media/returns-free-post-label.pdf</path>
            <label>Free Returns Label</label>
        </action>
    </block>
</customer_account>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<customer_account>
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-"               template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer" json="params">
            <name>free_returns_label</name>
            <path />
            <label>Free Returns Label</label>
            <params>{"_direct":"media\/returns-free-post-label.pdf"}</params>
        </action>
    </block>
</customer_account>
```

Comment: Genius - Thanks very much, this has done the trick!